# Incorrect output of parents for a search result in a tree structure

Tags: html, django, tree

I’m trying to enter parents for the search result so that the user understands in which node the value is located. The output is not correct. How to remove the extra ones????

models.py

```python
class Composition(MPTTModel):

    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', db_index=True, verbose_name='Родительская категория')
    mapping = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Отображение в дереве состава')
    id_drawing = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/image/', blank=True, null=True, default='null', verbose_name='Рисунок')
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Номер позции в родительской категории')
    designstion = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, verbose_name='Обозначение')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='null', verbose_name='Наименование')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='null', verbose_name='Описание')
    quantities = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default='null', verbose_name='Количество в родительской категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Альт. заголовок")

    objects = TreeManager()
    @property
    def drawing_url(self):
        if self.id_drawing and hasattr(self.id_drawing, 'url'):
            return self.id_drawing.url

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['designstion']


    class Meta:
        # unique_together = [['parent', 'slug']]
        verbose_name = 'Спецификация'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Спецификация'


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('manual:catalog_page', args=[str(self.pk), str(self.slug)])

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.designstion)
```

---

view.py

```python
def get_ancestors(unit):
    unit.designstion = unit.get_ancestors()
    return unit
def catalog(request):

    catalog_list = models.Composition.objects.filter(mapping=True)

    if request.GET.get('q') != None:
        question = request.GET.get('q')

        #   seach_catalog =map(get_ancestors, Composition.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=question)|Q(designstion__icontains=question)))**

        return render(request,
                  'catalog.html',
                  {
                      'catalog_list': catalog_list,
                      'seach_catalog': seach_catalog,

                  })
    else: 
        return render(request,
                  'catalog.html',
                  {
                      'catalog_list': catalog_list,

                  })
```

---

html

```html
<ul>
{% for unite in seach_catalog %}
    <li><a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ unite.name}}. 
  </a> <br>
        <div> {{ unite.designstion }}</div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

Output results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdLoD.png)

Necessary:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5v7Z.png)